# Redshift copy doesn't insert data into my table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have table SampleTable

and run the following Redshift command through a SQL Client (JackDB)

```
copy SampleTable
from 's3://bucket-name/backup/data.csv.gz'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=xxx;aws_secret_access_key=xxx'
gzip
csv;
```

the command does return

> Executed successfully  Updated 0 rows in 2.771 seconds.

but no data are inserted into empty table SampleTable

```
select count(*)
from SampleTabe
```

return 0

there are 100MB data in data.csv.gz

Comment: But what does that 100MB of data look like?

Comment: Could you give us an example of your data? The command itself looks good to me. I'm guessing your data format might be a cause.

Comment: @Masashi Miyazaki  thanks for the response. solved by myself, the data do not correspond to the query. I should include delimiter to overwrite the default and IGNOREHEADER 1 to skip the csv header. just bothered by the fact that no stl_load_error is recorded in this case

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot thanks for the response. solved by myself, the data do not correspond to the query. I should include delimiter to overwrite the default and IGNOREHEADER 1 to skip the csv header. just bothered by the fact that no stl_load_error is recorded in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved by myself, the data do not correspond to the query.

I should include delimiter to overwrite the default and IGNOREHEADER 1 to skip the csv header.

just bothered by the fact that no stl_load_error is recorded in this case

Comment: what do you mean with "the data do not correspond to the query"?